# How to setting Camera options in Blender

Tags: python, blender

i try to create car's type game, but when i choose camera view , a view is not real every building have miss shape its look like perspective view .So i finding how to config it

Answer (score 1):

your grammar is really bad but i think i understand what you are asking. When you use a camera you have to zoom in until the box fills your screen.